# I am receiving a syntax error for a character not in my code

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am trying to recursively add column names for a long list and keep receiving a syntax error. There is a character at the beginning of each item that should not be included, hence the [1:].

```
for i in range(0,len(stat_list)):
    cur.execute( '''
    ALTER TABLE PDB_id ADD {} TEXT '''.format(stat_list[i][1:]))
```

The error is:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "/": syntax error
```

Comment: If you print out the resulting SQL statements, the syntax error should be obvious.

Comment: There must be a slash in the text from `stat_list[i]`.

Comment: Also, why are you using `for i in range(0,len(stat_list))`?  `for stat in stat_list` is so much cleaner...

Comment: @JohnGordon You were right! I hadn't realised that would throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was one of the final items containing the '/'. Problem solved.